# Zend_forward error Cannot redeclare class Bootstrap

Tags: php, zend-framework

When I call (in my **AdminController**) the `_forward` function, i get this error

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Admin_Boot in /www/application/modules/admin/Boot.php on line 33
```

Actually, my website's structure is:

```
#Application/
|--Bootstrap.php
|--#modules
|----#admin
|------Boot.php
|------#controllers
|------#view
|----#default
|------Boot.php
|------#controllers
|------#view
```

(I have not placed everything, but the most important is here)

So, if I call the admin module, I'm gonna call Bootstrap.php, and after, Admin_Boot.php ...
All it's ok, it's just the _forward function who cause me some trouble ...

I need help

Comment: Are you using the autoloader? If not, do you have a `require` instead of a `require_once` somewhere?

Comment: I have in my **index.php** `include "Zend/Loader.php"; Zend_Loader::registerAutoload();`

Comment: can you post your `Boot.php` file

Comment: I also use loadFile in my helper controller ...

Comment: Just remember to mark correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using [`Zend_Loader::loadFile()`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.loader.load.html), think to set the third argument to **TRUE**;

```
Zend_Loader::loadFile("Boot.php", $dirs, true);
```